# Finding difference in two timestamp

Tags: php

I am trying to display how much time is gone for the comment has been posted. I am confused now i am trying many way but does not seems to work.

My code just giving **years ago** as output.

here is my code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$newtime = $date->format('U');
$oldtime = $row['time'];
$diffrence = $newtime - $oldtime;
$date = new DateTime("@$diffrence");
$sect = round($date->format('s'));
$mint = round($date->format('i'));
$hout = round($date->format('H'));
$dayt = round($date->format('d'));
$mont = round($date->format('m'));
$yeat = round($date->format('Y'));

if ($yeat > 1970){
    $disptime = "years ago";
} else if ($yeat < 1970) {
    $disptime = "$mont months ago";
} else if ($mont < 0) {
    $disptime = "$dayt days ago";
} else if ($dayt < 0) {
    $disptime = "$hout hours $mint min ago";
} else if ($hout < 0) {
    $disptime = "$mint min $sect sec ago";
} else {
    $disptime = "$sect sec ago";
}
```

**Edited** Getting near to solution after changing it yeat 0 to 1970

**Solved but other way finding tutorial and making my own code here is solved**

```
$start_date = new DateTime($row['timestamp']);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
$yeat = $since_start->y;
$mont = $since_start->m;
$dayt = $since_start->d;
$hout = $since_start->h;
$mint = $since_start->i;
$sect = $since_start->s; 

if ($mint == 0 && $hout == 0 && $dayt == 0 && $mont == 0 && $yeat == 0){
    $disptime = "$sect sec ago";
} else if ($hout == 0 && $dayt == 0 && $mont == 0 && $yeat == 0) {
    $disptime = "$mint min ago";
} else if ($dayt == 0 && $mont == 0 && $yeat == 0) {
    $disptime = "$hout hours ago";
} else if ($mont == 0 && $yeat == 0) {
    $disptime = "$dayt days ago";
} else if ($yeat == 0) {
    $disptime = "$mont months ago";
} else {
    $disptime = "$yeat years ago";
}
```

Comment: You should be using [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.diff.php) and then accessing the members of `DateInterval`.

Comment: Tip: UNIX timestamps are *absolute times*. Subtracting two UNIX timestamps which are close gives you a date near January 1st 1970. Your `$yeat` will always have a value of around 1970.

Comment: yes that is what is happening. @deceze

Comment: Need to solve it out as my million of record is saved in 'U' FORMAT

Comment: Re your "solved but.." code: warning -- `365*60*60*24` does **not** provide a year's worth of seconds. You're forgetting about leap years. You should use the built-in PHP functions to avoid bugs like that. (see my answer for `Datetime::diff()` code)

Comment: I updated my solved part :) @Spudley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's DateTime class has a `Diff()` method which does exactly what you want.

Your code would look something like this:

```
$date    = new DateTime();
$rowDate = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('U',$row['time']);

$interval = $date->diff($rowDate);

if($interval->y) {
    echo $interval->format('%y years');
} elseif($interval->m) {
    echo $interval->format('%m months');
} elseif($interval->d) {
    echo $interval->format('%d days');
} elseif($interval->h) {
    echo $interval->format('%h hours');
} elseif($interval->i) {
    echo $interval->format('%i minutes');
} elseif($interval->s) {
    echo $interval->format('%s seconds');
}
```

Comment: @deerox - I missed the `CreateFromFormat`, so have added that. That will help it work with timestamp. glad it was helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

See the TimeHelpers from cakephp:

```
public static function niceShort($dateString = null, $timezone = null) {
  if (!$dateString) {
   $dateString = time();
  }
$date = self::fromString($dateString, $timezone);

if (self::isToday($dateString, $timezone)) {
  return __d('cake', 'Today, %s', self::_strftime("%H:%M", $date));
}
if (self::wasYesterday($dateString, $timezone)) {
  return __d('cake', 'Yesterday, %s', self::_strftime("%H:%M", $date));
}
if (self::isTomorrow($dateString, $timezone)) {
  return __d('cake', 'Tomorrow, %s', self::_strftime("%H:%M", $date));
}

$d = self::_strftime("%w", $date);
$day = array(
__d('cake', 'Sunday'),
__d('cake', 'Monday'),
__d('cake', 'Tuesday'),
__d('cake', 'Wednesday'),
__d('cake', 'Thursday'),
__d('cake', 'Friday'),
__d('cake', 'Saturday')
);
if (self::wasWithinLast('7 days', $dateString, $timezone)) {
  return sprintf('%s %s', $day[$d], self::_strftime(self::$niceShortFormat, $date));
}
if (self::isWithinNext('7 days', $dateString, $timezone)) {
  return __d('cake', 'On %s %s', $day[$d], self::_strftime(self::$niceShortFormat, $date));
}

$y = '';
if (!self::isThisYear($date)) {
  $y = ' %Y';
}
  return self::_strftime(self::convertSpecifiers("%b %eS{$y}, %H:%M", $date), $date);
}
```

More info here:

- [Time Helper Source Code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.php#L315-347)
- [Usage Examples](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper%3a%3aniceShort)

Hope it gives you an idea on how to implement your own utility function.